# Unity: detect click event on UIVertex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

I am drawing lines on a canvas using the 'UIVertex' struct and I would like to be able to detect click events on the lines I have drawn.

Here is how I draw lines (largely inspired from this tutorial => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--LB7URk60A):

```
void DrawVerticesForPoint(Vector2 point, float angle, VertexHelper vh)
{
    vertex = UIVertex.simpleVert;

    //vertex.color = Color.red;

    vertex.position = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * new Vector3(-thickness / 2, 0);
    vertex.position += new Vector3(unitWidth * point.x, unitHeight * point.y);
    vh.AddVert(vertex);

    vertex.position = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle) * new Vector3(thickness / 2, 0);
    vertex.position += new Vector3(unitWidth * point.x, unitHeight * point.y);
    vh.AddVert(vertex);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: In your click handler check the coordinates of the mouse click against every point in the line.

Comment: How do I get the coordinates of every point in the line?

Comment: If you know the start point and end point there should be a mathematical function that can describe if a point is on the line or not. You may need to do some algebra (remember `y = mx + b` ). See: https://virtualnerd.com/algebra-1/relations-functions/graphing-linear-equations/identifying-linear-equations/check-point-line-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I have found thanks to this post:

```
public bool PointIsOnLine(Vector3 point, UILineRenderer line)
{
    Vector3 point1 = line.points[0];
    Vector3 point2 = line.points[1];

    var dirNorm = (point2 - point1).normalized;
    var t = Vector2.Dot(point - point1, dirNorm);
    var tClamped = Mathf.Clamp(t, 0, (point2 - point1).magnitude);
    var closestPoint = point1 + dirNorm * tClamped;

    var dist = Vector2.Distance(point, closestPoint);


    if(dist < line.thickness / 2)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The `UILineRenderer` class is the class I have which represents my lines.

`line.points[0]` and `line.points[1]` contain the coordinates of the two points which determine the line length and position. `line.thickness` is the... thickness of the line :O